# Make a new array by repeating some rows of an old array in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I have an array:

```
julia> a = [1 1; 2 2; 3 3; 4 4; 5 5; 6 6; 7 7;]
7×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7
```

And I make a vector that specifies how many times each row gets repeated in the new array:

```
julia> r = [0; 2; 0; 4; 0; 1; 0;]
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
 0
 2
 0
 4
 0
 1
 0
```

The output that I want is:

```
julia> a_repeated = [2 2; 2 2; 4 4; 4 4; 4 4; 4 4; 6 6;]
7×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  2
 2  2
 4  4
 4  4
 4  4
 4  4
 6  6
```

How do I get there? I thought I would use the [`repeat`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/linalg.html#Base.repeat) function, but I can't seem to understand how `inner` and `outer` work.

Comment: X-ref: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16443

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [`rep` function from DataArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataArrays.jl/blob/d86f7f4e6c3853bf68c1d83eda2a85634ce61738/src/deprecated.jl#L122-L142), this is simple and efficient.  It's deprecated there, though, so I'd pull it out and define it yourself:

```
function rep(x::AbstractVector, lengths::AbstractVector{T}) where T <: Integer
    if length(x) != length(lengths)
        throw(DimensionMismatch("vector lengths must match"))
    end
    res = similar(x, sum(lengths))
    i = 1
    for idx in 1:length(x)
        tmp = x[idx]
        for kdx in 1:lengths[idx]
            res[i] = tmp
            i += 1
        end
    end
    return res
end
```

Like `sample`, it works on vectors and not matrices, so we do the same song and dance as in [Sample rows from an array in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733042/sample-rows-from-an-array-in-julia).  Compute the indices of the rows and then use those to index into the matrix:

```
julia> idxs = rep(axes(a, 1), r)
7-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 2
 4
 4
 4
 4
 6

julia> a[idxs, :]
7×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  2
 2  2
 4  4
 4  4
 4  4
 4  4
 6  6
```

Comment: Thank you. I selected this answer as it was much faster than the other one for a large array.

Comment: possible to update this answer, @Matt B.? The current Julia seems not to like something in the syntax of the rep function any more.

Answer (score 2):

we can use `repeat` and array comprehension to get the result:

```
julia> a[2,:]'
1×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  2

# inner=(2,1)
# 2: repeat twice in the first dimension
# 1: don't repeat in the second dimension
julia> repeat(a[2,:]', inner=(2,1)) 
2×2 Array{Int64,2}:          
 2  2
 2  2

# returns empty array
julia> repeat(a[2,:]', inner=(0,1))
0×2 Array{Int64,2}

julia> vcat([repeat(a[i,:]', inner=(r[i],1)) for i in indices(a,1)]...)
7×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 2  2
 2  2
 4  4
 4  4
 4  4
 4  4
 6  6
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate seeing how to do this in one line. The other answer was faster on my machine so I selected it.